# how can we get DeviceType, DeviceOS & DeviceUniqueId in angular 4.3.1

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to fetch `DeviceType`, `DeviceOS` and `DeviceUniqueId` in angular4 using **ng2-device-detector v-0.1.0**, earlier I was using angular1  and it was working, however for some reason I shifted to angular 2 & 4, and it stops working, I did try few other things,  but unable to fetch this info.

Helping hands will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try "ng2-device-detector": "^1.0.0", I am using the ng2-device-detector in angular 4.3.1

Comment: use `useragent` in your document.